# Find ungrouped elements in array using Regex in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex

By "upgrouped" I mean elements that are uniq to its left and its right elements.

Example:

```
arr =  ["a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "c", "c", "d", "b"]
```

We can group arr like this  `[["a", 3], ["b, 1], ["a", 1], ["c", 2], ["d", 1], ["b", 1]]`. Let's say once a letter is "grouped" we are not going to pick any other ungrouped instances of that letter.

So our final answer would be `arr = ["b", "d"]`

What could be a great option to replace the "regex" part in `arr.select{|chr| chr(/\regex/)}` (if there is no other ways)?

**Edit:** added "b" in the end of array. `arr.count("b") == 2`, but since "b" is ungrouped, it is still part of the return array.

Comment: Do you mean to get the elements that appear just once in `arr`?

Comment: `once a letter is "grouped" we are not going to pick any other ungrouped instances of that letter.` - Then can't use regex.

Comment: @Mikhail why do you need to group elements? It's requirenment? Probably will help: `arr.select{ |i| arr.count(i) == 1 }`

Comment: Why is the first `"b"` mapped to `["b", 1]` and the second (at the end) mapped to `"b"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it in two steps **without** regex:

```
banned = arr.chunk(&:itself).select { |e| e.last.size > 1 }.map(&:first)
#=> ["a", "c"]

arr.uniq - banned
#=> ["b", "d"]
```

Basically first we get the list of elements that are grouped and need to be rejected, and then remove those elements from original array.

Here is a step by step example (for `banned` list):

```
arr.chunk(&:itself).to_a           #=> [["a", ["a", "a", "a"]], ["b", ["b"]], ["a", ["a"]], ["c", ["c", "c"]], ["d", ["d"]], ["b", ["b"]]]
   .select { |e| e.last.size > 1 } #=> [["a", ["a", "a", "a"]], ["c", ["c", "c"]]]
   .map(&:first)                   #=> ["a", "c"]
```

*Notice that `to_a` is added only to show the content of the `Enumerable` that results from `chunk`, but it is not used in the final solution since `map` can be executed on any `Enumerable` object.*

Another option to get `banned` list could be using `each_with_object`:

```
arr.chunk(&:itself).each_with_object([]) { |elem, result| result << elem[0] if elem[1].size > 1 }
#=> ["a", "c"]
```

This will only iterate `arr` twice (first option will iterate it 3 times).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how I'd use a regular expression for this problem, but the method [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) can be used to advantage.

Let `grouped` and `ungrouped` respectively be arrays of elements of a given array `arr`, where `grouped` are the grouped elements and `ungrouped` are the ungrouped elements. Every element is grouped or ungrouped.

My understanding of the question is that we wish to construct an array

```
(ungrouped - grouped).uniq
```

where [Array#-](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-2D) is array difference.

It is clear that, for `i=1,..., arr.size-2`, `arr[i]` is ungrouped if `arr[i-1] != arr[i] && arr[i] != arr[i+1]`. It's not evident, however, how one determines whether the first and last elements of an array are ungrouped. The definition states that, to be ungrouped, the element must differ from both of it's adjacent elements. Since the first and last elements only have one adjacent element, it follows that the first and last elements are never ungrouped.

The alternative interpretation is that an element is ungrouped if it differs from *all* of its adjacent elements (that being one for the first and last and two for all others). I will consider these two interpretations separately. For both,

```
arr = [["a", 3], ["b", 1], ["a", 1], ["c", 2], ["d", 1], "b"]
```

**Ungrouped elements must differ from both of their adjacent elements**

```
ungrouped, grouped = [arr.first, *arr, arr.last].each_cons(3).
  with_object([[],[]]) do |(p,c,n), (ungrouped, grouped)|
    (c==p || c==n ? grouped : ungrouped) << c
end
(ungrouped - grouped).uniq
  # => ["d"]
```

**Ungrouped elements must differ from all of their adjacent elements**

```
ungrouped, grouped = [nil, *arr, nil].each_cons(3).
  with_object([[],[]]) do |(p,c,n), (ungrouped, grouped)|
    (c==p || c==n ? grouped : ungrouped) << c
end
(ungrouped - grouped).uniq
  # => ["b", "d"]
```

This assumes that no elements of `arr` equal `nil`.

The steps for this second interpretation are as follows.

```
a = [nil, *arr, nil]
  #=> [nil, "a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "c", "c", "d", "b", nil]
b = a.each_cons(3)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [nil, "a", "a",..., "d", "b", nil]:each_cons(3)>
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
b.to_a
  #=> [[nil, "a", "a"], ["a", "a", "a"], ["a", "a", "b"], ["a", "b", "a"],
  #    ["b", "a", "c"], ["a", "c", "c"], ["c", "c", "d"], ["c", "d", "b"],
  #    ["d", "b", nil]]
```

Continuing,

```
d = b.with_object([[],[]])
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [nil, "a", "a",..., "d", "b", nil]:
  #     each_cons(3)>:with_object([[], []])>
d.to_a
  #=> [[[nil, "a", "a"], [[], []]], [["a", "a", "a"], [[], []]],
  #    [["a", "a", "b"], [[], []]], [["a", "b", "a"], [[], []]],
  #    [["b", "a", "c"], [[], []]], [["a", "c", "c"], [[], []]],
  #    [["c", "c", "d"], [[], []]], [["c", "d", "b"], [[], []]],
  #    [["d", "b", nil], [[], []]]]
```

If one examines the return value for the construction of this enumerator, you can see it can be thought of as a *compound* enumerator.

```
ungrouped, grouped = d.each do |(p,c,n), (ungrouped, grouped)|
  (c==p || c==n ? grouped : ungrouped) << c
end
  #=> [["b", "a", "d", "b"], ["a", "a", "a", "c", "c"]]
ungrouped
  #=> ["b", "a", "d", "b"]
grouped
  #=> ["a", "a", "a", "c", "c"]]
e = ungrouped - grouped
  #=> ["b", "d", "b"]
e.uniq
  #=> ["b", "d"]
```

Let's take a closer look at the calculation of `ungrouped` and `grouped`. The first element of the enumerator `d` is passed to the block and the block variables are assigned values.

```
(p,c,n), (ungrouped, grouped) = d.next
  #=> [[nil, "a", "a"], [["b", "a", "d", "b"], ["a", "a", "a", "c", "c"]]]
p
  #=> nil
c 
  #=> "a"
n 
  #=> "a"
ungrouped
  #=> []
grouped
  #=> []
c==p || c==n
  #=> "a"==nil || "a"=="a"
  #=>  true
```

Therefore,

```
grouped << c
  #=> ["a"]
```

The remaining calculations are similar, as are the calculations under the first assumption concerning the first and last elements of the array.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `with_object` method, it definitely comes handy.